# <nb-tab> How to call a user defined function in nebular nb-tab while switching tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, nebular

`(changeTab)` isn't working for me. I want to call a specific function when I switch to a specific tab in Nebular Theme in Angular.

Answer (score 5):

Not easy to give to help because you did not provide any examples of our code. At this stage i'm mostly guessing but you should figure out why `(changeTab)` does not work.

Make sure you apply the `(changeTab)` on the `<nb-tabset>` tag rather than the `<nb-tab>` tag.

```
<nb-tabset (changeTab)="yourFunc($event)">
    <nb-tab tabTitle="some title">
        <!--Tab content goes here-->
    </nb-tab>
<nb-tabset>
```

Works perfectly fine for me.